# Delete Ubuntu Desktop With Applications Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

I want to delete the ubuntu desktop components including the applications, e.c.t. I want to replace it completely wiht the unity desktop, exept That I want just the applications that come wiht unity to be on, and not the gnome ones. I have already found a list of applications to remove, but there are a few packages that are not to be uninstalled, so it does not work.

Comment: Your release of Ubuntu would be helpful.  Unity was a GNOME alternative desktop, and used GNOME applications so most will not change. You can add Unity desktop with `ubuntu-unity-desktop` the package (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ubuntu-unity-desktop)

Comment: @guiveric Done!

Comment: Does `ubuntu-unity-desktop` have all the apps with it? I know unity 8 (unity8.io) does not. @guiverc

Comment: And is there a way to have the unity8 apps with it? @guiverc

Comment: You were not specific, and I assumed Unity 7 (as used in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS & 16.04 LTS, and available for 18.04 LTS & 18.10). Unity 7 apps and everything found on Unity is included in that package (opening the link shows that). Unity 8 was Qt based (not GTK+ as found in Gnome) thus its apps are different (being Qt as found in KDE (Kubuntu) or LXQt (Lubuntu 18.10 onwards)) being supported by UBports & not Canonical. I've seen many blogs about it, but don't recall facts as didn't interest me.

Comment: A quick look (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=unity8&searchon=names) shows `unity8-desktop-session-mir` is available for 16.04 LTS & before, but I don't see it for 18.04 LTS.

Comment: I am gonna put up another question for the unity8 applications

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

Answer yes to the question for lightdm default.

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Remove GDM and restore automatic login

```
sudo apt remove gnome-shell
```

Restart the computer

If you choose automatic login, go in user account, unlock and set the switch off and on again. Lock user account and restart.

```
unity --version
```